# How to work with Dot Matrix LCDs?

Tags: lcd

I am new to LCDs and I am trying to interface my LCD (used in Nokia 3310 cell phone) with PC via Parallel port. I searched on Google and I found many programs and schematics which can used to draw image on it. But I want to understand the actual functions of the pins of LCD named as VCC, RES, etc, so that I can develop my own program on C#.Net.

The Pin arrangements are as follows:

[image]

Comment: If this is a surplus custom part, there's a possibility that the datasheet is not available, and that various existing projects (code and writeup) based on reverse engineering could be the extent of documentation readily available.

Comment: Information about the nokia 3310 LCDs is all over the web, google for instance "nokia 3310 datasheet". A PC might not be the most appropriate platform to start experimenting with these LCDs, consider a microcontroller, maybe an arduino.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to want to get the datasheet for the device. I'm pretty sure it has a SPI serial interface which is pretty 'standard'. A better option than your parallel port might be to get a USB SPI device like the [Bus Pirate](http://dangerousprototypes.com/bus-pirate-manual/). I think you'll find some routines on the net and you might look at Make or Sparkfun.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to second Kenny's mention of the datasheet.

Pretty much every electronic component or assembly created has a datasheet produced with it.

The datasheet contains everything you need to know about how to use said component - its electrical characteristics, any protocols it uses, external component requirements, pin assignments, etc.

All the information you are looking for is in the datasheet.

Comment: I need to know the meaning and function of pins

Comment: They're in the datasheet.